# Could not find goal 'java-Dexec.mainClass=com.mystique.application.Main_Runner' | Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Tried to build and run my local Cucumber project in Jenkins with 2 build steps. `1st` step was successful `clean install`, but  `2nd` steps (exec:java-Dexec.mainClass="com.mystique.application.Main_Runner") is throwing attached error.

Logs:

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\807240\.jenkins\workspace\Cucumber
[Cucumber] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Soumen\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:/Soumen/Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton/Cucumber/pom.xml -s C:\Soumen\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\conf\settings.xml -gs C:\Soumen\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\conf\settings.xml clean install && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< com.opencredo:cucumber-jvm-parallel >-----------------
[INFO] Building cucumber-jvm-parallel 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.3 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:jar:1.8 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.8 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The artifact junit:junit-dep:jar:4.11 has been relocated to junit:junit:jar:4.11
[WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Soumen\Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton\Cucumber\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Soumen\Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton\Cucumber\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 101 source files to C:\Soumen\Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton\Cucumber\target\test-classes
[WARNING] /C:/Soumen/Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton/Cucumber/src/test/java/com/mystique/roomsteps/RunTests.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /C:/Soumen/Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton/Cucumber/src/test/java/com/mystique/roomsteps/RunTests.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test (default-test) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Soumen\Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton\Cucumber\target\cucumber-jvm-parallel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Soumen\Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton\Cucumber\target\cucumber-jvm-parallel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Soumen\MavenRepo\com\opencredo\cucumber-jvm-parallel\1.0-SNAPSHOT\cucumber-jvm-parallel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Soumen\Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton\Cucumber\pom.xml to C:\Soumen\MavenRepo\com\opencredo\cucumber-jvm-parallel\1.0-SNAPSHOT\cucumber-jvm-parallel-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.053 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-01T18:36:10+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Cucumber] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Soumen\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\mvn.cmd -f C:/Soumen/Cucumber_WorkspacePhoton/Cucumber/pom.xml -s C:\Soumen\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\conf\settings.xml -gs C:\Soumen\Softwares\apache-maven-3.6.1\conf\settings.xml exec:java-Dexec.mainClass=com.mystique.application.Main_Runner && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.496 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-01T18:36:16+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'java-Dexec.mainClass=com.mystique.application.Main_Runner' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 among available goals exec, help, java -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

Comment: what is the goal of 2nd job? just make sure that installed jar is deployed in the correct folder for execute job.

Comment: Goal is          exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass="com.mystique.application.Main_Runner"

Comment: [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ cucumber-jvm-parallel ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mystique.application.Main_Runner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: Can you tell me any whether any specific jar I have to download for this error? [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project cucumber-jvm-parallel: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.mystique.application.Main_Runner ->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss a space between exec:java and -Dexec.mainClass="com.mystique.application.Main_Runner"

Comment: Now I am getting below error.  [WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mystique.application.Main_Runner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project cucumber-jvm-parallel: An exception occured while executing the Java class. com.mystique.application.Main_Runner -> [Help 1]

Comment: did you try to have only one maven call with "clean install exec:java..." in one shot ?

Comment: Also make sure your class com.mystique.application.Main_Runner is in src/main/java, not src/test/java. And that you do find the Main_Runner.class in the target/classes (or test-classes.) If it is in test-classes, add this to your options : -Dexec.classpathScope=test

Comment: Yes it is inside test-classes, So the goal should be  exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope="com.mystique.application.Main_Runner" , correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: no, the goal should be : exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mystique.application.Main_Runner" -Dexec.classpathScope=test